# How do i access Controller value through the Json in view and loop through in jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
 public ActionResult OrderDetails()
    {
        var data = new DataContainer();
        ViewBag.OrderDetails = data.GetOrderDetails();
        return Json(data);                     
    }
```

Above is my contoller.

```
 public Detail GetOrderDetails()
    {
        return (from user in db.Users
                          join detail in db.OrderDetails
                          on user.Id equals detail.UserId
                          where (detail.DateAdded != null)
                          select new Detail
                          {
                              FirstName = user.FirstName,                                 
                              Email = user.Email,
                              Gender = user.Gender,
                              Phone = user.Phone,
                              Destination = detail.DestinationCode,
                              CarrierCode = detail.CarrierCode,  
                              OrderId = detail.OrderId
                          }).FirstOrDefault();            
    }
```

This is my Class

and here is my ajax jquery method

```
function doAjax(type, url, data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            callback(data);
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
}
```

Now i want to retrieve my controller value through the json in my ajax jquery method. How can i access them?

Answer (score 3):

Put a debugger statement to your JavaScript code.

like so:

```
function doAjax(type, url, data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            callback(data);
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can watch what object comes back from your controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are jquery code is hitting your action method and server is properly returning json, You can access it like this.

```
function doAjax(type, url, data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

           alert(data.FirstName);
           alert(data.Email);
           alert(data.Phone);

            callback(data);
        },
        error: function (a,b,c) {
            alert(c);
        }
    });
}
```